# C# int showing 48 instead of 0

Tags: c#

Currently I know that 48 is the ASCII equivalent for 0 but I am doing everything to get the normal decimal form. Please view my code below to see what I am trying to do exactly. The truckUpgradeArray is basically 6 0s as a string, but when I put them into the TRUCKS array which is an array of ints it shows as 48. Even though when debugging and seeing what the value of u is it shows as 0.

```
void loadUpgrades()
{
    truckUpgradeArray = null;
    int arrayPos = 0;
    truckUpgradeArray = PlayerPrefs.GetString("truckUpgradeArray");
    Debug.Log(truckUpgradeArray);
    var truckArray = truckUpgradeArray.ToCharArray();
    int o = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < truckArray.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = truckArray [i];
        int u = (int) c;
        TRUCKS[o, arrayPos] = u;
        arrayPos++;
        if (arrayPos == 3) {
            o++;
            arrayPos = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 48 == `'0'`, not `0` - huge difference

Comment: maybe do `u = (int) c - 48`??? (Or perhaps a bit more readable: `u = (int) c - '0'`)

Comment: Why are you converting to a Character Array?

Comment: `Even though when debugging and seeing what the value of u is it shows as 0.` u has the value of 0 before you assign the character value c to it. Pay attention to this when you step through your code. Check the value of u right after the line `int u = (int) c;` has been executed...

Comment: More relevantly, 48 is the UTF-16 code unit value for '0'. `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 is one of several character encodings for the Unicode character set. If you ever see the ASCII character set in use, it'll be per particular specifications that would be essential.to know then. Any similarity between one character encoding and another is generally irrelevant. Exactly one applies at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
int u = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c);
```